# Freeing memory allocated to a pointer vs freeing memory allocated to what the pointer points to

Tags: c, pointers

Following is the implementation of a stack struct in C. I need to write a function (not a method) to dispose off an existing stack and ofcourse free any memory allocated for it on the heap. the dispose (stack *s) function takes in a pointer to a stack that is to be disposed off.

```
typedef struct {
    int allocatedLength;
    int logicalLength;
    int elementSize;
    void *elems;
} stack;
```

If I implement the dispose() function as follows, will it lead to some memory never being freed?

```
void dispose (stack *s) {
    free (s->elems);
}
```

In the above implementation, I am only freeing the memory allocated to elems, which is not even on the heap. We need to remember that elems is a pointer to something. Shouldn't we be freeing that something, instead of freeing the memory allocated to the pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand: `free(p)` does *not* free the memory for `p`, but the memory for `*p` -- that is, the memory *pointed to by `p`*. Thus, you *are* correctly freeing the allocated memory to which you stored a pointer in `s->elems`, and all is well.

Feel free to blame everyone who talks about "freeing a pointer" for this misnomer, when really they should be saying "freeing the memory to which I have a pointer".

Answer (score 0):

What you will free all depends on if you will allocate the struct `stack` dynamically or not. If you don't allocate it dynamically, you only need to free (the dynamically allocated memory)  that `elems` is pointing to. Which is exactly what you are doing with `free (s->elems);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are allocating memory for the struct stack, then free() should be for struct only. Not for the member of it. Here is a sample program which allocates memory for whole struct. 
free() should be done to structure pointer s.

If `free (s->elems);` is uncommented and `free (s);` is commented, the printf prints the assigned data. struct's memory will not be freed and leads to memory leak.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int allocatedLength;
    int logicalLength;
    int elementSize;
    void *elems;
} stack;


void dispose (stack *s) {
    //free (s->elems); 
    free (s);
}

int main()
{

 stack *p = malloc(sizeof(stack));

 if(p == NULL)
    {
            printf("\n Memory Allocation Error\n");
            return 0;
    }

  p->allocatedLength = 10;
  p->logicalLength = 20;
  p->elementSize = 30;

  dispose(p);

  /* This printf is undefined behaviour if stack's ptr is freed. If the elem only freed, then it prints data */
  printf("\n allocatedLength: %d\nlogicalLength:%d\nelementSize:%d", p->allocatedLength, p->logicalLength, p->elementSize);


return 0;
}
```